# Text loses its transparent background when opacity of graphics is reduced

Tags: graphics3d, text, style

By default `Text` has a transparent background. However, combined with other graphics with the opacity option, the text background turns to white and even overrides explicitly defined background.

For example:

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity @.5, Cylinder[]}, Text @ Style["Text", Large]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

How can one fix this behavior to display transparent background?

Comment: On 11.1 version it works well.

Comment: I am using 11.1 as well

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Got it. Added sample code.

Comment: Using you sample code, I can not reproduce your problem with V11.0.1 running on OS X 10.10.2. The graphics rendered when I evaluate your code looks exactly like the image you wanted, not like the image you post.

Comment: With 11.1.0 I can reproduce on Win 7 Ent.

Comment: @Edmund, could you please check out whether switching render engine to OpenGL/Mesa fixes the problem?

Comment: I don't observe this problem with version 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem only arises when DirectX is used as a rendering engine. Switching to OpenGL/Mesa fixed the problem in my case.

Comment: How do you switch between rendering engines?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, the user-friendly way is `Edit` -> `Preferences...` -> `Advanced` tab -> `Open Option Inspector` button -> expand the 'Graphic Options' branch -> `Rendering Options` -> `3DRenderingEngine`